# Billing problem when trying to activate google ads api on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to activate the Google Ads Api for my Google Cloud project. But every time I try it throws the following error:

```
An unknown error occurred when attempting to verify your billing information. Please try again or return later

Tracking number: NUMBER
```

I was able to activate other APIs normally. Contacted the billing support and they didn't find any billing problem. Google Ads API support is offline.

Any ideas on how to solve it or how to get help? :)

Comment: Google Ads API presently in beta [1] and you may directly file any support related issue to their community support page [2]. It seems you are already communicating there [3] and definitely your problem will be solved soon. 

[1] https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/15235?hl=en
[2] https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/support
[3] https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/1E4AHs18Igc

Comment: Thanks Shafiq. Looks like they fixed the bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't receive any further contact from Google Team but they seem to have solved my problem. After 1 week blocked on this task I just tried again and it worked.

Anyone with a similar problem should try to contact their google group: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api